# How to Access TemplateField in Code Behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, templatefield, detailview

```
<asp:DetailsView...
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="My CheckBox" SortExpression="DataID" >
         <InsertItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="T01cbx" runat="server" Visible ="false" Checked='<%# Bind("DataID") %>' AutoPostBack="True" " />
         </InsertItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
```

I want give an ID or Name for the above TemplateField and access it from the code behind. Is there anyway to find the TemplateField by giving and ID or Name? This is inside a DetailView.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use LINQ to get a `TemplateField` by it's `HeaderText`:

```
TemplateField cbField = DetailsView1.Fields.OfType<TemplateField>()
                       .Where(f => f.HeaderText == "My CheckBox")
                       .FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Thanks Tim, but I get this error. System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection' does not contain a definition for 'OfType' and no extension method 'OfType' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataControlFieldCollection' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: @Harsha: Have you added `using System.Linq;`?

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do this in the past, but never found a better way than writing a function that loops all columns and find the one i want to modify by it's SortExpression.

This is the function i used to hide/show columns by their SortExpression:

```
public void ShowHideGridColumnBySortExpression(string sortExpression, bool show)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < gvProducts.Columns.Count; i++)
    {
        if (gvProducts.Columns[i].SortExpression != null && gvProducts.Columns[i].SortExpression == sortExpression)
        {
            gvProducts.Columns[i].Visible = show;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```